# Adding JAR in Hive is giving error as "Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: /user/hive/warehouse/abc.jar does not exist."

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-udf

I created a UDF and exported the jar as abc.jar.

Copied the jar in hdfs at /user/hive/warehouse.

Now, I am getting below errors:

```
hive> ADD JAR /user/hive/warehouse/abc.jar;
/user/hive/warehouse/abc.jar does not exist
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: /user/hive/warehouse/abc.jar does not exist.
hive>
```

When I do, `hadoop fs -ls /user/hive`, I can see **abc.jar** at **/user/hive/warehouse** path.

Where am I doing wrong and what is the solution for this?

Comment: Place your UDF jar on the local file system of the hive client machine and give the absolute local path of the jar in the ADD JAR command

Answer (score 1):

When you add jar from hdfs you use the following statement :

```
ADD jar hdfs://namenode/user/hive/warehouse/abc.jar;
```

you are not notifying that you are adding the jar from hdfs . That is the cause of your error.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The way, you are mentioning the path, it will look the file in local file system.
Either place it there, or use **hdfs://** like this

```
hive> ADD JAR /user/hive/warehouse/abc.jar   => local filesystem
hive> ADD JAR hdfs://namenodei/user/hive/warehouse/abc.jar   => In hdfs
```

Answer (score 0):

Above options are valid for current sessions only. So every time you need to write `ADD JAR`.
In order to add it permanently recommended ways are as follows.

1. add in hive-site.xml

   `<property>
   <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
   <value>file://localpath/yourjar.jar</value>
   </property>`
2. Copy and paste the JAR file to the `${HIVE_HOME}/auxlib/` folder

Comment: response doesnt aim at answering OP's question.